# Where is weapon damage stated?

Tags: weapons, damage, odnd

So I've read from multiple sources that weapon damage in the original D&D booklets is 1d6 regardless of weapon. However, reading through the books, I can't find reference to weapon damage at all.

The books refer to ***Chainmail*** as the default combat system, but that has casualties determined directly by die rolls, it doesn't deal with individual unit damage as far as I can tell. The alternate combat system also doesn't seem to mention it.

What page is weapon damage stated on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> All attacks which score hits do 1–6 points damage unless otherwise noted.

That's from ***Men & Magic***, the last line on page 19. Variable damage by weapon type was introduced in the ***Greyhawk*** additions to the Alternative Combat System. The table for that is on page 15 of Greyhawk.